# How to use full width of Phone in xaml?

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-phone

I have 3 controls in a `Grid.Row` but how can I make them use the full width of the page?

This is my xaml:

```
 <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Image Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Source="/Assets/image1.png"
            Height="25"
            Width="25" />

      <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
               Margin="10,0,0,0"
               Text="{Binding InputText, Mode=TwoWay}"
               BorderBrush="Black"
               BorderThickness="2"
               VerticalAlignment="Center">
      </TextBox>

      <Button Grid.Column="2"
              BorderThickness="2"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Command="{Binding AddTextCommand}"
              Margin="10,0,0,0">
       <TextBlock x:Uid="ButtonText" />
       </Button>
 </Grid>
```

This is now the result:

As you can see it is aligned left, how can I make it use the full width?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code only shows 3 controls (`Image`, `TextBox`, `Button`), while your screenshot gives 4 controls. I suppose the full width control on top is missing, but that's no problem to answer the question.

If we break down your XAML, you have:

- First column width Auto, filled with an image.
- Second column width 140, filled with a TextBox
- Third column width * (or the rest of the space), filled with a Button

On the button you have placed `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` (default is Left), in which you're saying: only use the space necessary and put the control on the right side. If you want to use the full width available, you have to use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`.

```
 <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Image Grid.Column="0"
            Source="/Assets/image1.png"
            Height="25"
            Width="25" />

      <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
               Margin="10,0,0,0"
               Text="{Binding InputText, Mode=TwoWay}"
               BorderBrush="Black"
               BorderThickness="2"
               VerticalAlignment="Center">
      </TextBox>

      <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Uid="ButtonText"
              BorderThickness="2"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Command="{Binding AddTextCommand}"
              Margin="10,0,0,0" />
 </Grid>
```

Note that I have also removed the `TextBlock` from the `Button` and move the `x:Uid` tag to the button. Simply use `ButtonText.Content` in your resources to have your button localized, there's no need to place a `TextBlock` in there.

Comment: Hey, the above textbox is in another grid row. What I want is that the button ends where the above textbox ends. I added horizontalalignment but nothing changes

Comment: Is this grid placed in a StackPanel (or similar control)? Then you'll have to put `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the Grid/StackPanel as well, because controls inside a StackPanel only take the necessary width, not the full width. The code above is tested and proven, so if it doesn't work, there's an issue up the tree.

Comment: Indeed I had a unnecessary stackpanel, removed it and it works like you said. Thank you!